# Different binaries with "Archive" and "Build for Archiving" in Xcode4

Tags: xcode, xcode4, release, archive

I'm trying to figure out how to build a release version of my Cocoa app the right way.

So far I've used the **Build for Archiving** option, and grabbed the app bundle from deep inside Xcode's DerivedData folder.

Today I tried the **Archive** menu command, and used **Share** to save my app bundle. It seems cleaner and less hacky. Digging through the DerivedData folder just doesn't feel like the right thing to do.

But here's the thing. The binaries inside those two app bundles aren't the same. As far as I can see, they behave the same. But `diff` shows that they aren't equal, and their sizes suggest that there are more than trivial differences. For example, my release binary made with "Build for Archiving" has a size of 29,576 bytes. The "Archive" version is only 21,536 bytes.

Archiving and Archive *sound* like they should basically be the same thing. Why are they different? Which one is "better"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that the **Archive** command does all that **Build for Archiving** does, plus some extra actions to make a proper archive. If you perform **Build for Archiving** and **Archive**, then view the Log Navigator (Cmd+7), you will see a few additional lines for the **Archive** action at the end. Most notably it performs **Strip** on your binary, which removes all the debug symbols from you binary, and thus making it smaller.